# Why is one Expression Allowed to be Rational and Not the Other?

Tags: calculus

The following expression can't take on a rational value for some real $h$:
$$\frac{\sqrt{4 + h} -2}h$$

But this expression can:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}$$

This is confusing me because the only factor that seems to have an impact on rationality/irrationality is the term $\sqrt{4+2}$, which appears in both expressions. So, what am I missing?

Can someone explain to me why one expression can take on a rational value and not the other?

Comment: Doesn't the second expression contain a root in its denominator?

Comment: $\sqrt{4+h}=-2$. No real $h$ satisfies this, since the square root is positive by definition. A complex $h$ however ...

Comment: Yes, which is to avoid the indeterminate $\frac k0$. For the first equation, when $h=0$ the expression is indeterminate. For the second equation there is no real $h$ that turns the expression into an indeterminate form.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout what? there is no equation here, where did you get an equals sign?

Comment: @JohnDoe To get an indeterminate we have to get the denominator equal to $0$. So $\sqrt {4+h} + 2=0 \implies \sqrt {4+h}=-2$ for which there is no _real_ value of $h$.

Comment: You are misusing the terminology (in English - other languages may use these terms differently). Neither expression is "rationalized". The first expression has a *rationalized denominator*, while the second expression has a *rationalized numerator*. Which is preferable depends on the problem and what else you are doing with it. But "rationalized" by itself is not a fit description for either expression.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Ok, I still don't really understand what you're doing (and what you mean by an intermediate, and what this achieves), but its ok, I don't particularly care.

Comment: @JohnDoe I mean an indeterminate. This is something whose value we don't know. For example $\infty, \frac 00,\frac 10, \infty-\infty$ are all expressions whose values are unknown to us. I apologise if I could not explain clearly enough.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I think there's been some confusion haha. I understood your first comment completely, but I didn't know what cansomeonehelpmeout was doing, which is who I was supposed to address in my previous comment. I guess they were doing what you're doing -  showing that this manipulation removes the indeteminate issue (this all makes sense). My issue was, their comment didn't comment on how that was useful to the question. It makes sense now I guess.

Comment: @JohnDoe oops my bad. I have the memory of a goldfish _and_ an unreal scroll button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the following expression considered not rationalized $\frac{\sqrt{4 + h} -2}h$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}$ is?

Well neither of these expressions is *rational*, but presumably this appears in the context of computing limits such as:
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{4 + h} -2}{h}$$
which, by direct substitution, leads to the indeterminate form $\tfrac{0}{0}$. In this example, you can then *rationalize the numerator* as follows:
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{4 + h} -2}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\left(\sqrt{4 + h} -2\right)\color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{4 + h} +2\right)}}{h\color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{4 + h} +2\right)}}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac1{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}$$
and you arrive at the limit of your second expression. Although now the denominator isn't rational, you have rationalized the numerator and eliminated the 'problem', i.e. the indeterminate form $\tfrac{0}{0}$.

So coming back to your question:

> Why is the following expression considered not rationalized $\frac{\sqrt{4 + h} -2}h$ and $\frac1{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}$ is?

It's safer to say that you have *rationalized **the numerator*** by replacing the first expression by the second. Note that this is not specific to the numerator since it also works the other way around; in the following limit, you could *rationalize the denominator* with the same trick:
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h}{\sqrt{4 + h} -2}$$